# Different between !a==-1 and a!=-1

Tags: c++

Different between '(!server[i].type==-1)' and '(server[i].type!=-1)'

Server is a struct array have type and amount two members.

```
server[0] type：-1 amount： 100
server[1] type： 0 amount：  50
server[2] type： 1 amount：  50
```

I want to calculate the sum of amounts of type not -1.
I think these two codes are same

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
    if(!server[i].type==-1)
         total+=server[i].amount;
}

for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
    if(server[i].type!=-1)
         total+=server[i].ptime;
}
```

But i found the first one not work.Can someone tell me why this happen?Thank you very much.

Comment: `!server[i].type==-1` ~ `(!server[i].type)==-1`

Comment: Missing parentheses and lack of research about operator preference is a primary reason.

Comment: If one "not work", why would you think the "codes" are the same? Did you consider doing any research into the meaning of the symbols you're typing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well `server[i].type != -1` is true if `server[i].type` is not equal to `-1`.

On the other hand, `!server[i].type==-1` due to [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) evaluates as `(!server[i].type) == -1`, which is never going to be true because the left hand side is either going to be `0` or `1`, unless `server[i].type` has `operator!` overloaded... which I'm assuming is not the case. The equivalent version would be `!(server[i].type == -1)`.

Answer (score 1):

The unary operator `!` is the boolean inversion operator, i.e.

```
!true  → false
!false → true
```

The binary operator `!=` is the "not equal" operator, i.e. the boolean inverse of "equal to"

```
a != b → true <=> a == b → false
```

or written slightly differently

```
(a != b) == !(a == b)
```

Take note of putting the boolean inverse operator in front of a pair of parentheses. The reason for that is, that the boolean inversion operator has a higher precedence than the boolean equality operator. Which means that `!a == b` is equivalent to `(!a) == b`.

In C and by extension C++ every nonzero value is considered boolean true, and zero is boolean false. Also the result of boolean operators is specified to be either 0 (→false) or 1 (→true).

Now let's look at your two different expressions "`!a==-1` and `a!=-1`"

Since `!` is a boolean operator the result of `!a` is defined to be either `0`, or `1`. So in case `a` is nonzero, i.e. true `(!a) → 0` thus `0==-1 → false` as for a being zero `(!0) → 1` thereby `1==-1 → false`. Hence the expression `!a==-1` will always yield false.

`a!=-1` on the other hand is comparing the value of a with -1. Its boolean algebra equivalent would be `!(a==-1)`.

Comment: I'm not sure it's fair to say that C++'s boolean rules are "by extension" from C, since it had real boolean types long before C did. All C had was what might generously be described as library convention. No?

Comment: Oh and those are expressions, not statements :)

Comment: Finally, "its" not "it's" please.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: native boolean type or not, from the day it saw the light of the world C had boolean operators that adhere to boolean algebra (You know about George Boole, after which boolean algebra is named, right). arrgh, normally I'm the one complaining about misuse of the apostrophe. Stupid, stupid…

Comment: Yes, thank you, I am well versed in boolean algebra. For example, I know that it has no concept of underlying representation or about the semantics of conversion to and from integers. Meanwhile, getting back to the point, I submit that C++ converts non-zero to `true` and zero to `false` not because it was old C library convention, but because it just makes general sense. :) Though I concede there may have been [really loose] code cross-compatibility concerns.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: "I know that it has no concept of underlying representation or about the semantics of conversion to and from integers."` – you see, there's nothing in the world that can stop me from writing `ℤ → {False, True}: x ↦ False for x = 0 else True ; {False, True} → {0, 1}: y ↦ 0 for y = False, 1 for y = True`. There, I just amended Boolean algebra with numerical representation and I can now use elements of the set ℤ instead. – You're splitting hairs here, for whatever reason, but it doesn't enhance the topic at hand in the slightest.

Comment: Creating your own rules and predicates doesn't automatically inject them into Boole's algebra. I'd expect you to know that! Anyway, I may be "splitting hairs" but as for "enhancing the topic at hand", I think I was quite clear at the beginning that I am disputing your assertion that C++'s integer/boolean conversions are "by extension from C". You don't want to teach incorrect information in your answers, do you? So surely identifying inaccuracies is "enhancing the topic at hand". You're welcome!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Okay, so I don't want to drag this along any further than required. The thing is: C++ grew out of C (no matter what some people claim) and in fact the first few released specifications put forward into the ANSI/ISO standardization process *did not* support a language-built-in boolean type. In fact the first mention of a C++ `bool` type happened in 1993 and it took another 4 years until the commonly used compilers would all support it; until then you had to rely on the C semantics. Stroustroup on the topic: http://www.stroustrup.com/hopl-almost-final.pdf

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: And about attaching it to Boolean algebra: Well, it's a homomorphism for sure, which I presume should suffice. But if you want to put a nail into the coffin reformulate it as isomorphism between type classes and then there's no more arguing about it.

Comment: Yeah mate I'm well aware of the history of the language. The fact remains, come standardisation in 1998, C++ was "based on" a version of C that did not have boolean types (and, by extension [sic] did not dictate the underlying representation of either `true` or `false`). Yet this standardised C++ _did_. That's just a fact. Do you dispute it? So how can C++'s bool conversion rules be an "extension of" C's? You say you "don't wish to drag this along any further than required" yet you keep marching down tangents  to distract, instead of addressing my concern.